# Rails: Check which method initiated save inside :before_save

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, model, crud

I want to run a method that tracks changes to a records's attributes inside the CRUD, but only when they're saved with the Update action. I have this inside the model now:

```
before_save :check_changed
def check_changed
  puts "Period Contributions Changed? : #{period_contributions_changed?}"
  puts "Total Contributions Changed? : #{total_contributions_changed?}"
  puts "Period Expenditures Changed? : #{period_expenditures_changed?}"
  puts "Total Expenditures Changed? : #{total_expenditures_changed?}"
end
```

But this runs on the creation of new records as well. Is there a test I can perform inside the check_changed method to determine whether a record was created or updated? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the conditional callback :if and :unless

```
before_save :check_changed, unless: :new_record?
```

Or you could use 'new_record?' in your method

```
def check_changed

  return if new_record?

  puts "Period Contributions Changed? : #{period_contributions_changed?}"
  puts "Total Contributions Changed? : #{total_contributions_changed?}"
  puts "Period Expenditures Changed? : #{period_expenditures_changed?}"
  puts "Total Expenditures Changed? : #{total_expenditures_changed?}"
end
```

Edit: Should also check out

```
after_save :check_changed, on: [:update]
```

Docs are [here](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#conditional-callbacks)